# Ambiguity in calling function. Implicit conversion?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, overload-resolution

```
#include <string>

void f(std::string&& rref){
}

void f(std::string s){ 
}

int main() {
    std::string s = "s";
    f(std::move(s));
}
```

This code causes an ambiguity and I don't know why, perhaps, I made explicit conversion to *rvalue* reference.

My idea is that *rvalue* reference can be implicitly converted to just *lvalue*.
But I am not sure. Please explain.

Comment: What is the ambiguity? Was there a compiler error message?

Comment: ambiguity error reproduced: `error: call of overloaded 'f(std::remove_reference<std::basic_string<char>&>::type)' is ambiguous` note: candidates are: ...

Comment: Why do you need two separate overloads here?

Comment: I don't need. I asked becaue I am inquisitive ;)

Comment: Expressions are never of reference type.

Comment: @AlanStokes could you explain me what do you mean?

Comment: @J.Doe technically the *type of the expression* `std::move(s)` is `std::string` with value category *xvalue* .

Comment: @M.M please refer me to read about it with examples if you can :). Don't refer me to: cppreference because I dislike it.

Comment: I don't have any better suggestions than cppreference or stackoverflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::string` can be initialized from an rvalue of type `std::string`  . So the second function is a candidate.

It's not a feasible idea to have value and rvalue-reference overloads. A more normal setup is to have rvalue-reference, and  lvalue-reference overloads:

```
void f(std::string&& rref);
void f(std::string & lref);   // or const&
```

This would cover all the use cases.

Comment: So it does mean that std::string&& returned by std::move can be converted ( by converting constructor) std::string( std::string&& other) to string?

Comment: @J.Doe Yes that's right - `s` is initialized from the argument using that constructor

Comment: @M.M When I change lines in main to `std::string &&s = "s"; f(s);`, then there's no ambiguity. Are you sure that's the constructor issue, not `std::move` xvalue-ness?

Comment: In your changed code, the expression `s` has value category *lvalue* , so `f(std::string&&)` is not a candidate. The `f(std::string)` is called.

Comment: So, what is more important in matching function? Argument's type or argument's category value?

Comment: @J.Doe they are both required to match

Comment: Ok. So please refer me when I can find information about it since C++11

Comment: look up 'what are xvalues' on stackoverflow